# Azure Web Job Upload using java client

Tags: java, azure, azure-webjobs

**History for context:**
I am trying to run a web job from an HTTP Client. The file is a ZIP file . and contains a java class and bat file to run that java class. This runs okay when i do from POSTMAN. But when i use HTTP client, i get the following error always " '---i-NPsGbTVUpaP0CeJxMQVrHoDHvaxo3' is not recognized as an internal or external command" - Please help – Jagaran yesterday

@Jagaran if it only happen from some clients, it is likely unrelated. Please ask a new question – David Ebbo 21 hours ago

No any HTTP Client i am using in java, it is the same. it works in CURL or loading from web console. My sample code below – Jagaran 2 hours ago

No any HTTP Client i am using in java, it is the same. it works in CURL or loading from web console.

Do you have any sample Java based HTTP Client where I can publish Azure Web Job? I have tried all Java REST clients.

May be i am doing something wrong. The error I get in Azure console is '---i-NPsGbTVUpaP0CeJxMQVrHoDHvaxo3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, [08/25/2017 09:30:22 > e7f683: ERR ] operable program or batch file.o

I feel Content type = applciation /zip is not happening correctly when using java. Please help us.
Sample Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;


/**
 * @author jagaran.das
 *
 */
public class AIPHTTPClient {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "rawtypes" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {

            URI  uri = new AIPHTTPClient().getURI();
            HttpResponse<InputStream> jsonResponse = Unirest.put("https://<URL>/api/triggeredwebjobs/TestJOb")
                .basicAuth("$AzureWebJobTestBRMS", "XXXXX")
                    .header("content-disposition","attachement; filename=acvbgth.bat")
                    .field("file", new  FileInputStream(new File(uri)) 
                        ,ContentType.create("content-type: application/zip"),"AzureWebJob.zip").asBinary();
             System.out.println(jsonResponse.getStatusText()); 


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public InputStream readZip() {
        ZipFile zipFile = null;
        ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry("run.bat");

        InputStream stream = null;
    /*  try {
            zipFile = new ZipFile("/Users/jagaran.das/Documents/work/AIP/AzureWebJob.zip");
            java.util.Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
            while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
                ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } */
        try {
            stream = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
   return stream;

    }


  public URI getURI() throws MalformedURLException {
    File file = new File("/Users/jagaran.das/Documents/work/AIP/azure-poc/AzureWebJob.zip");

    URI fileUri = file.toURI();
    System.out.println("URI:" + fileUri);


    URL fileUrl = file.toURI().toURL();
    System.out.println("URL:" + fileUrl);

    URL fileUrlWithoutSpecialCharacterHandling = file.toURL();
    System.out.println("URL (no special character handling):" + fileUrlWithoutSpecialCharacterHandling);
    return fileUri;
       }

}
```

Comment: Can you check if your `.bat` file has an UTF-8 BOM? If so, re-save the file without the BOM.

Comment: Done. There is no BOM. Actually i feel it is trying to execute the ZIP file itself. Detail Log below:   [08/25/2017 09:30:22 > e7f683: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[08/25/2017 09:30:22 > e7f683: SYS INFO] Job directory change detected: 
[08/25/2017 09:30:22 > e7f683: SYS INFO] Run script 'test.bat' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[08/25/2017 09:30:22 > e7f683: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\WebJobTest1008\ctwey5uk.i5u>---i-NPsGbTVUpaP0CeJxMQVrHoDHvaxo3

Comment: Can we have a look at the contents of that .bat file?

Comment: Nevermind that, reading more carefully it looks like curl is successful with uploading. Fiddler should tell you the full story. Install, do a test run from Java and capture the full request headers + body, then compare with curl's.

Comment: content type is not coming in charles proxy ... any other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been a little too harsh in my answer before really trying stuff out. Apologies. I've now tried out your snippet and looks like you're hitting an issue with Unirest - probably [this one](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/issues/165).

My advice would be to just move to [Apache's HTTP library](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPut.html).
Here's a working sample:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.EntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import java.io.File;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        File sourceZipFile = new File("webjob.zip");
        String kuduApiUrl = "https://yoursitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/app_data/jobs/triggered/job988/";

        HttpEntity httpEntity = EntityBuilder.create()
        .setFile(sourceZipFile)
        .build();

        CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
            "$yoursitename", "SiteLevelPasSw0rD"
        );
        provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
            .build();

        HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut(kuduApiUrl);
        putRequest.setEntity(httpEntity);
        // Kudu's Zip API expects application/zip
        putRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/zip");

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(putRequest);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String resBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(statusCode);
            System.out.println(resBody);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

That's sending `Content-Type: application/zip` and the raw zip contents in the body (no multipart horse manure). I've probably over-engineered the sample.. but it is what it is.

[image: Raw body]

The upload is successful and the WebJob published:

[image: WebJob]

Comment: POST is not allowed for that request. Only PUT

Comment: So PUT doesn't support .header() you're saying?

Comment: no no Microsoft REST API for Azure uploading web job zip, does not support POST, only PUT. No when doing PUT for a zip file from a java client, it is not working.

Comment: Awesome and great help. This is working. I think URL was also one of the issue along with Library. Very nice and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Glad for you that you have solved the issue and I try to provide a workaround for your reference.

Deploy WebJob to azure , in addition to using `REST API`, you can also use the `FTP` way. Of course, the premise is that you need to know the directory uploaded by webjob via `KUDU`.

I offer you the snippet of code below via FTP4J libiary：

```
import java.io.File;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;

public class UploadFileByFTP {

    private static String hostName = <your host name>;
    private static String userName = <user name>;
    private static String password = <password>;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // create client
            FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
            // connect host
            client.connect(hostName);
            // log in
            client.login(userName, password);
            // print address
            System.out.println(client);

            // change directory
            client.changeDirectory("/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/continuous");
            // current directory
            String dir = client.currentDirectory();
            System.out.println(dir);

            File file = new File("D:/test.zip");
            client.upload(file);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

You can follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-ftp) to configure your parameters.